# Generating cold plasma using a Piezo Transformer

Tags: transformer, manufacturing, solid-state-devices, piezoelectricity

I am trying to generate cold plasma using a multi layer piezo transformer.
My understanding was that it was as simple as applying a 15 Vpp to the transformer, but it did not work.
I was trying to mimic the effect of the piezobrush PZ2 from reylon plasma, and going from the image attached  from reylon´s website I thought it would be simple.[image]

How can I make this work? Any further reading that could be recommended?
Does my transformer need to have copper inner electrodes?

The specific transformer I am using is a Multi Layer Piezo Transformer 55 KHz 3W, part number SMMTF53P3S45 from steminc dot com.

Thank you for reading.